# What happens when a class inherits another class and implements an interface that have identically named property?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Eg.

```
public interface IPerson {
  int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
  public int Id { get, set }
}
```

then,

```
public class Employee: Person, IPerson {
  ...
}
```

Will this cause any confusion to the compiler when we refer to that property? Will the compiler know which property are we referring to? or it does not matter?

I tried to do as explained above and my code seems to work without issue. So i just want to get some explanation on this scenario.

Thanks...

Comment: In C#, when a class inherits another class and implements an interface, and both the base class and the interface have identically named properties, there is no confusion for the compiler. The compiler can distinguish between them based on their access modifiers and inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: For more understanding read up on explicit interface implementation

Comment: `IPerson.Id` will just be `Employee.Id` (inherited from `Person`) in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, you can't "confuse" the compiler like that.

The child class contains all methods and properties of the base class,  and since it's a `public` property that's enough to implement the interface.
In other words, the implementation of the interface already exist in the base class and you don't need to worry about it.

The one thing that can go wrong is if the base class property isn't `public`.
In such cases, you must also [explicitly implement the interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) in the child class -

```
public class Employee: Person, IPerson {
  // this doesn't have to be an auto-implemented property...
  int IPerson.Id { get; set; }   
...

}
```

This will allow you to keep two properties called `Id`, one only accessible when the class is references as `IPerson` and one only accessible as declared in the base class (i.e. `protected`, `internal` and so on).

Comment: It's possible that you can't confuse the compiler, but you can definitely confuse yourself when default implementations are involved: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76949033/126014

Comment: @MarkSeemann Good point. Personally I haven't worked with this feature because I thought it might be too confusing so I don't really have much to say about it.